# Using data on healthsites.io for small project

Tags: medical, uses-of-open-data, open-definition

healthsite gathers data for open and complete approach to creating a global health facility data set by  leveraging the power of OpenStreetMap

**question**: in corona - pandemic times, can we takt the data for a little service site that maps the hospitals that are available for the public health.  in other words: can we access and get the dataset from healthsites.io to work on the set of  data to publish it to serve the folks in a. italy, or b. barbados or c. Senegal!? - with a little online-map project that makes use of the maps and data -we obtain form healthsites.io!? is this doable!?

**answer**: i guess so - since the data is under the Open Data Licence:  (see Open data collaboration https://healthsites.io/ Through collaborations with users, trusted partners and OpenStreetMap we will capture and validate the location and contact details of every facility and make this data freely available under an Open Data License (ODBL) )

is this correct - can we use the datase of healthsiters.io for a little (private) online project that serves the people in a. Senegal or b. Barbados. or c somewhere else!?

what do you thikn - can we do a little project with the dataset of helathisites.io

what if i want to work on the data of the set eg on Barbados or Italy.:

- https://healthsites.io/map?country=Barbados
  https://healthsites.io/map?country=Italy
  https://healthsites.io/map?country=france

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is released under Open Data License (ODBL), have a look at the  [TLDR Legal for ODBL](https://tldrlegal.com/license/odc-open-database-license-(odbl)). From your description, it seems like your use of the data indeed fits the conditions of the license.

Comment: hi there - many thanks sboysel for the quick reply and for sharing your insights into this - and thanks for the link to the Notes regarding the ODBL ;)

Comment: hello dear  sboysel: btw i will have to ask the healthsite.io team whether i can use any of the maps they produce or other data that is used and created over there. 
btw: on a first sight: as it is inscribed into the rules of the licence and legal terms: what can be said regarding the the creations of the healthside-group: aren ´t they are being asked to "release" the data & things they have created among the above mentionend licence!?
What do you think!?